# Listitem added in to second row in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, listview

Im getting data from mysql database and adding this data to ListView.
When im doing this, the data are starting added to second row. First row is empty.But it loads all data correctly.Only thing is first row in databse is get added in second row in the listview.

```
private void CreateSessionList() {
    SessionList.View = View.Details;
    SessionList.Font = Listctrlfont;

    connection.Open();
    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sessiontbl";
    MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ada.Fill(dt);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
        ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["SessionID"].ToString());
        listitem.Font = Listitemfont;
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["InstID"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Trainee"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SessDt"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["ModelID"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["ModelName"].ToString());
        SessionList.Items.Add(listitem);
    }
}
```

What i did wrong?

Comment: Is SessionList empty before you start adding the items? If you add `MessageBox.Show(SessionList.Items.Count.ToString());` before `connection.Open()`, what number do you see?

Comment: It returns 1. When i add Clear() , by seeing below solution. Now it returns 0.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a placeholder item in the list view from the designer.
Call clear on the items before you start populating to make sure you are starting with a clean slate.

This also means you would be able to reload from the dB whenever you wanted.

```
SessionList.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the first row of Datatable contain the column names.In this case, you have to start from i=1 in the dt.Rows collection.